# several backgroung images do not show up on iPad

Tags: html, css, image, ipad

My website has some background images that do not show up on iPad.

My code for these images is:

```
#section-biography { background: transparent url(../img/bio.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 0; }
```

I read here
[(Really) Long Background Image Does Not Render on iPad Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046143/really-long-background-image-does-not-render-on-ipad-safari?newreg=bd8fc20bd627442c875b612921d17c1f)
that the max size for background images on iPad is:

```
width * height ≤ 3 * 1024 * 1024
```

If I have several different images on my background, does the above formula apply to the SUM of all backgound images, in other words do the formula become:

```
width_img_1 * height_img_1 + width_img_2 * height_img_2 + .... width_img_n * height_img_n  ≤ 3 * 1024 * 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but it could have something to do with your background positioning:

[does a background-attachment of fixed work in iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779195/does-a-background-attachment-of-fixed-work-in-ios5)